# Entity Framework. Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am creating a list of objects and adding them to my `DbContext`, then saving them. The problem is I added a unique constraint to the database to stop objects with duplicate data.

Because the error is thrown on `SaveChanges`, I could try save each object individually and catch the error. Is that a poor solution and is there a better way to handle it ?

```
    using (FinanceDBContext financeDBContext = new FinanceDBContext())
    {
        foreach (var item in priceList)
        {
            item.Apimapping = null;
            financeDBContext.Price.Add(item);
        }

        financeDBContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

My `Price` object

```
public partial class Price
{
    public int PriceId { get; set; }
    public decimal LastPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Bid { get; set; }
    public decimal Ask { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int? ApimappingId { get; set; }

    public Apimapping Apimapping { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Pull the existing unique keys from the database first and only insert the ones that don't match. Even then, you still have to catch exceptions because of concurrency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check for duplicates in provide list

```
var distinctBids = priceList.Select(p => p.Bid).ToList();
if (priceList.Count != distinctBids.Count())
    return BadRequest(); // even the provided list have duplicates;
```

Check for duplicates for input values

```
if (context.Price.Any(e=> distinctBids.Contains(e.Bid)))
    return BadRequest(); // check for duplicates in database
```

after that its safe to insert values

```
// Now its safe to add new prices;
foreach (var item in priceList)
{
    item.ApimappingId = null;
    context.Employees.Add(item);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

you will also need to put all of above statements in one traction as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx)